# Can I get a static lifetime from Clap's arg parser?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is it possible to get `static` lifetimes from Clap's arg parser?

```
let args = App::new(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"))
      .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
      .author(env!("CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS"))
      .about(env!("CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION"))
      .bin_name(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"))
      .arg(
        Arg::with_name("db-name")
          .short("d")
          .long("db-name")
          .value_name("NAME")
          .help("Sets database name")
          .takes_value(true),
      )
      .get_matches();

let db_name = args.value_of(val)?; // <-- want as &'static str
```

Currently getting them as `&str`. The end goal is to have a single config object that lasts for the lifetime of the program. I don't really want to copy the values around either, just to remain in a single location.

Comment: Ask yourself: what does `'static` mean. Is it possible to create a `'static` lifetime during runtime?

Comment: I have and the answer is yes because I know there's a lazy_static crate :) but I'm not familiar with it so would want to know if there's better ways of achieving this?

Comment: You must leak memory to do that. Check my proposed duplicate.

Comment: Thanks French, it's similar for sure but mines aimed at the Clap crate in particular. I thought there might be a way to request it as `static` via that crate's API. I know lazy_static exists, but thought there might be a solution available without needing another crate.

Comment: @willsquire Clap builds this string at runtime, thus it won't leak any memory behind your back to give you a static string.

Comment: At your place, I wouldn't leak the memory if you have a lot of configuration. I would create a struct with the configuration and pass it to every function that needs it.

Comment: I have, see: https://github.com/WillSquire/Graphy/blob/master/api/src/main.rs and https://github.com/WillSquire/Graphy/blob/master/api/src/config/mod.rs. But it needs thread safety and I want to pass a ref to everything that needs it rather than copy. I'm open to ideas? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192723/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-willsquire).